# .shファイルでcfgファイルの書き換え

Tags: ubuntu, shellscript

shファイルが保存してあるのとは別のディレクトリにあるcfgファイルの書き換えをshファイル内に記述したいのですがどのような方法が考えられるでしょうか。

現状では
`./usercreate.sh`
`cd ~/airflow`
`sed -i -e "4c\dags_folder = /home/test2/dags" airflow.cfg`

のような形で実行しているのですが、後ろの２行で行っている処理も
usercreate.sh内に記述してしまいたいと考えています。

Answer (score 0):

`./usercreate.sh`に

```
sed -i -e "4c\dags_folder = /home/test2/dags" ~/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

を加えれば良いだけかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！(T_T)！
（素人すぎてそんなことすらわかっていませんでした・・・早速回答頂けてたすかりました！ありがとうございます）